# Display error message for multiple input type file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple file inputs in my form and I check file size and file type on every input file. I have a general DIV where error message appears, but what I want is to be able to show an error message for every different file input in a different DIV. This code works fine just for the general DIV:

```
$("form#MyForm").submit(function() {
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        var file = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0];
        $('#error').empty();

        if (file && file.size > 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
            $('#error').addClass('alert alert-danger');
            $('#error').append("File size exceeds 5 MB");
            return false;
        }

        if (file && file.type != 'application/pdf') {
            $('#error').addClass('alert alert-danger control-group');
            $('#error').append("Only PDF files");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="file" id="file1">
<div id="error1"></div>

<input type="file" id="file2">
<div id="error2"></div>

<input type="file" id="file3">
<div id="error3"></div>

<input type="file" id="file4">
<div id="error4"></div>
```

How can I loop over the file inputs and display an error message for the input which does not meet the requirements?

Comment: I would suggest use `jquery validate` plugin or validate individual input file on `onChange` event of each input file.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in an .each() to loop through each input element. Then for each one, you could use `.next()` to locate the next div from the file, so you could give them all the same class name (e.g.: "errorMessage")

```
$( "input").next("div.erroMessage").append(your error message here);
```

Where the HTML would be

```
<input type="file" id="file1">
<div class="errorMessage" id="error1"></div>

<input type="file" id="file2">
<div class="errorMessage" id="error2"></div>

<input type="file" id="file3">
<div class="errorMessage" id="error3"></div>

<input type="file" id="file4">
<div class="errorMessage" id="error4"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike, can you explain me how to wrap the code in an .each()?

Comment: You would do this... `$("input[type='file']").each(function(){
var errorDiv=$(this).next("div.errorMessage");
errorDiv.append("This is the error for id " + errorDiv.attr("id"));
})`

Comment: So you are looping through each input that has a type of file. The for each of these elements, getting the div contained within it that has a class of errorMessage. Then you can append the text with your relevant text (in the example above, I have just picked up the id attribute to prove it is looping - https://jsfiddle.net/m38p0uga/

Answer (score 0):

You can make slight changes in the script to loop through each of the divs that can display error,

```
    if (file && file.size > 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
        $('.error-display-div').each(function(){
          $(this).addClass('alert alert-danger');
          $(this).html("File size exceeds 5 MB");
        });
        return false;
     }
```

And to the HTML just add a common class to each of the error divs, like this below,

```
     <input type="file" id="file1">
     <div class="error-display-div" id="error1">
     </div>

     <input type="file" id="file2">
     <div class="error-display-div" id="error2">
     </div>

     <input type="file" id="file3">
     <div class="error-display-div" id="error3">
     </div>
```

Comment: thanks to take your time to answer the question, I've implemented your solution but the same error message appears in every input file with and without a file

Answer (score 0):

@Mike's answer is correct. Here is another option for you to consider. In this example, I was working on an implementation based on array group of elements, using each jquery function and find for the child elements how input and div.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>submit demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>multiple validation</p>
<form action="javascript:alert( 'success!' );" id="myform">
  <div>
    <div name="files[]" >
        <input type="file">
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div name="files[]">
            <input type="file">
            <div></div>
    </div>

    <div name="files[]">
            <input type="file">
            <div></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
<span></span>

<script>
$( "#myform" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $( "div[name='files[]']" ).each( function( index, element ){
        var file = $(element).find('input');
        var iSize = ($(file)[0].files[0].size / 1024);
        console.log(iSize);
        console.log(file.val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase());
        if (file && iSize > 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
            //$('#error').addClass('alert alert-danger');
            $(element).find('div').text("File size exceeds 5 MB");
            //return false;
        }
        if (file && file.type != 'application/pdf') {
            //$('#error').addClass('alert alert-danger control-group');
            $(element).find('div').text("Only PDF files");
            //return false;
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: using your solution, I'm passing a 9MB pdf file and get the error message 'Only PDF files'